# Cannot send headers; headers already sent

Tags: magento

I`ve got a problem with the magento cart.

Cannot send header; headers already sent /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/local/BTS/Checkout/Model/Observer.php, line 91

Report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:137:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/local/BTS/Checkout/Model/Observer.php, line 91";i:1;s:1601:"#0 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(105): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://www.puet...', 302)
#2 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(672): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://www.puet...')
#3 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(92): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('checkout/cart')
#4 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(225): Mage_Checkout_CartController->_goBack()
#5 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#6 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#7 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /homepages/14/d412931110/htdocs/shop/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:83:"/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wdWV0emNoZW4uY29tLw,,/product/229/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Do you have any solution for me please?

Comment: If I transfer die files to another server, the problem doesn`t appear.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your file may be you left

**echo ,
 Zend_Debug::dump() ,
 print_r()**

if you comment these so you can;t face the "Cannot send header; headers already sent" issue

If still the issue not solve then you left the space at the top of the file

so please both option you will fix the issue your self

Thanks
Jayram Prajapati

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

There`s no "echo , Zend_Debug::dump() , print_r()" in "observer.php"

Comment: If I transfer die files to another server, the problem doesn`t appear.

Comment: Problem solved! White-space classic issue!
Thank you for the your help!

Comment: Thanks sir i told  you there is space also but np we done that's good achievement for us

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!

There`s no `echo`, `Zend_Debug::dump()`, `print_r()` in `observer.php`.

Here`s the content:

```
class BTS_Checkout_Model_Observer {

    private $_shippingCode = 'royalmail';
    private $_country = 'DE';

    public function addShipping($params = null) {
        if (Mage::registry('checkout_addShipping')) {
            Mage::unregister('checkout_addShipping');
            return;
        }
        Mage::register('checkout_addShipping',true);

        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $quote = $cart->getQuote();

        if ($quote->getCouponCode() != '') {
            $c = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection');
            $c->getSelect()->where("code=?", $quote->getCouponCode());
            foreach ($c->getItems() as $item) { $coupon = $item; }

            if ($coupon->getSimpleFreeShipping() > 0) {
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->save();
                return true;
            }
        }

        try {
            $method = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
            if ($method) return; // don't overwrite what's already there if we have one set already

            if ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() == '') {
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($this->_country);
            }

            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

            $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
            $allowed_rates = array();
            foreach ($rates as $rate) {
                array_push($allowed_rates,$rate->getCode());
            }

            if (!in_array($this->_shippingCode,$allowed_rates) && count($allowed_rates) > 0) {
                $shippingCode = $allowed_rates[0];
            }

            if (!empty($shippingCode)) {
                $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
                if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
                if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
                if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
                if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
                if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
                $address->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
            } else {
                $address = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
                if ($address->getCountryId() == '') $address->setCountryId($this->_country);
                if ($address->getCity() == '') $address->setCity('');
                if ($address->getPostcode() == '') $address->setPostcode('');
                if ($address->getRegionId() == '') $address->setRegionId('');
                if ($address->getRegion() == '') $address->setRegion('');
                $address->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingCode)->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->save();
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->resetCheckout();

        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Load customer quote error'));
        }


    }

    public function getQuote() {
        if (empty($this->_quote)) {
            $this->_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        }
        return $this->_quote;
    } 
}
```

Thank you for your help!